# Remove preceding duplicate numbers in a file - bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

In the text file below "BEFORE FILE", how would I remove the duplicate numbers to make it look like the "AFTER FILE" below? The "_PRODxxxx," where the x's are the numbers, will stay in that format.

BEFORE FILE

```
NET_SalesD_PROD1111,mexico
NET_Sales4_PROD22,newjersy
NET_SalesG_PROD333,bull
```

AFTER FILE

```
NET_SalesD_PROD1,mexico
NET_Sales4_PROD2,newjersy
NET_SalesG_PROD3,bull
```

I have tried using sed and a regex capture group like "PROD[1-9]{2,4}" but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Where is your capture group?

Comment: please update the question with your actual `sed` attempt(s) and the (wrong) results generated by said code

Comment: will every line always have the numbers preceeded by `_PROD` and followed by a comma?

Comment: will the numbers always be a duplicate of a single digit? in other words is it possible to have `_PROD1234,` or `_PROD121212,` and if so then what would be the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a capture group to capture the first digit, and a back-reference to match repetitions of it. Then use the same back-reference in the replacement to produce just one of it.

```
sed -E 's/PROD([1-9])\1+,/PROD\1,/'
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** In case you are ok with Perl have it like this way then using regex and capturing group capability and using greedy match and then Lazy match capabilities in regex to achieve the required output.

```
perl -pe 's|^(.*_)(.*?)(\d)\3*(,.*)$|${1}${2}${3}${4}|'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using simple substitution in perl using capturing group to find duplicates and substitute it with itself followed by a `,`.

```
perl -pe 's|([0-9])\1*,|\1,|'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- all lines contain the string `_PROD[0-9]+,`
- we (effectively) want to keep the first number that comes after `_PROD`

One `sed` approach:

```
$ sed -E 's/(_PROD[0-9])[0-9]*/\1/' x
NET_SalesD_PROD1,mexico
NET_Sales4_PROD2,newjersy
NET_SalesG_PROD3,bull
```

Where:

- `(_PROD[0-9])` - (first) capture group matches on the string `_PROD<single_digit>` followed by ...
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `\1` - replace the match with the (first) capture group

Answer (score 0):

A long way if you want to `awk` it:

```
 awk -vc="PROD" '{

      split($1,h1,c)
      split(h1[2],h2,",")

      print h1[1]""c""substr(h2[1],1,1)","h2[2]

 }'
```